# Flutter remove all routes

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to develop a logout button that will send me to the log in route and remove all other routes from the `Navigator`. The documentation doesn't seem to explain how to make a `RoutePredicate` or have any sort of removeAll function.

Answer (score 481, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with the following code:

```
Navigator.of(context)
    .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

The secret here is using a RoutePredicate that always returns false `(Route<dynamic> route) => false`. In this situation it removes all of the routes except for the new `/login` route I pushed.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked successfully. Could you please send some link, where I can understand more....

Comment: I got a problem with this! On iOS, by using a native view as widget, after use your method the native view does not dispose properly and continue to exist, as a result i have a view that will be never used again running in a sort of background and impossible to dispose. This seems to happen just on iOS devices.

Comment: @LorenzoImperatrice Did you found fix for this issue? I'm having similar issue

Comment: I still have instances open even after using this. any other solution to push screen and remove rest of the stack?

Comment: How can we pass arguments with this approach.

Comment: I came here again year later after the first time saw it. Found answer helpful again and tried to upvote it. So sad that I can't upvote it twice!

Comment: @Developine I know it's quite late, but in case anyone else needs to pass arguments it can be done this way 
`Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false, arguments: { "key": "value"});`

Comment: what happen is return true? `(Route<dynamic> route) => true`

Answer (score 185):

I can do that using the following code snippet :

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
    LoginScreen()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

if you want to remove all the route below the pushed route, **RoutePredicate** always return **false**, e.g *(Route route) => false*.

Comment: if you want to send params on navigating page then you can use "Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/newRouteName", (r) => false, arguments: {
  "arg_1": firstArgument,
  "arg_2": secondArgument
});"

Comment: This code works for me.

Answer (score 54):

Another alternative is `popUntil()`

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/root'));
```

This will pop all routes off until you are back at the named route.

Answer (score 36):

Another solution is to use `pushAndRemoveUntil()`. To remove all other routes use `ModalRoute.withName('/')`

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    context,   
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Login()), 
    ModalRoute.withName('/')
);
```

Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html

Comment: This is really worked. for my scenario . I have a startup page. Which contain 2 buttons. one is login and the other is signup . once we go inside each of those buttons . inside there is a another route area which can navigate through each page. So if I dont use above code . it will go inside inside and inside like inception film. to prevent this code helps. Thanks for the answer. Awesome.

Answer (score 27):

In case you want to go back to the particular screen and you don't use named router can use the next approach

Example:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => SingleShowPage()),
                  (Route<dynamic> route) => route is HomePage
              );
```

With **route is HomePage** you check the name of your widget.

Comment: what is NoAnimatedRoute? Cant find class with such name in Flutter

Comment: @kashlo Don't pay attention =) It just my implementation can use MaterialPageRoute instead. But I've edited the answer, thanks.

Comment: (Route<dynamic> route) => route.isFirst) If some wants to remove until first route.

Comment: route is HomePage is not worked , I replaced HomePage with my widget name not worked, route.isFirst worked perfectly

Answer (score 20):

If you are using namedRoutes,

> This statement removes all the routes in the stack and makes the pushed one the root.

then you can do this by simply :

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/login", (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Where **"/login"** is the route you want to push on the route stack.

Answer (score 19):

use popUntil like following

`Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst);`

Answer (score 11):

I don't know why no one mentioned the solution using [SchedularBindingInstance](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html), A little late to the party though, I think this would be the right way to do it originally [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60408254/8253662)

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      '/login',
      (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
});
```

The above code removes all the routes and naviagtes to '/login' this also make sures that all the frames are rendered before navigating to new route by scheduling a callback

Answer (score 9):

In my case I had this painting
**Page 1 (Main) -> Page 2 -> Page 3 -> Page 4.**

**When I had to go to Page 4, the Page 2 and Page 3 going back did not have to appear, but I had to go to Page 1 again**. At this point going to Page 4 I did:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                      Workout()),
             (Route<dynamic> route) => route.isFirst);
```

**The instructions are: go to page 4 (Workout) and remove all previous pages up to 1, that is (Main).**

**In your case that can be to switch from anything to a Login, then:**

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                      Login()),
             (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

**That is, go to Login and remove all previous pages, because there is a false.**

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if I'm doing this right

but this suits my use-case of popping until by root widget

```
void popUntilRoot({Object result}) {
    if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
      pop();
      popUntilRoot();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer in case you don't use named routes. So elegant

Comment: How is the `Object result` parameter used? Is it required in this function?

Answer (score 7):

In my case this solution works:

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(" The Route you want to go to " , (Route route) => false);
```

Comment: if you want to go to login or register you can simply call the root ::::                                                       Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/ " , (Route route) => false);

Answer (score 6):

This is working for me. Actually,  I was working with **bloc** but my issue was login screen bloc. It was not updating after logout. It was holding the previous model data. Even, I entered the wrong entry It was going to Home Screen.

Step 1:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        UIData.initialRoute, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

where,
`UIData.initialRoute = "/" or "/login"`

Step 2:

It's working to refresh the screen. If you are working with Bloc then It will very helpful.

```
runApp(MyApp());
```

where,
`MyApp() is the root class.`

**Root class (i.e. MyApp)** code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final materialApp = Provider(
      child: MaterialApp(
          title: UIData.appName,
          theme: ThemeData(accentColor: UIColor().getAppbarColor(),
            fontFamily: UIData.quickFont,
          ),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          //home: SplashScreen(),
          initialRoute: UIData.initialRoute,
          routes: {
            UIData.initialRoute: (context) => SplashScreen(),
            UIData.loginRoute: (context) => LoginScreen(),
            UIData.homeRoute: (context) => HomeScreen(),
          },
          onUnknownRoute: (RouteSettings rs) => new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => new NotFoundPage(
                appTitle: UIData.coming_soon,
                icon: FontAwesomeIcons.solidSmile,
                title: UIData.coming_soon,
                message: "Under Development",
                iconColor: Colors.green,
              )
          )));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return materialApp;
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

Here is My **Logout** method,

```
void logout() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preferences.clear();

    // TODO: we can use UIData.loginRoute instead of UIData.initialRoute
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        UIData.initialRoute, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    //TODO: It's working as refresh the screen
    runApp(MyApp());
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this, it worked perfectly for me:

```
 Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
 context, '/loginscreen', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Make sure you add the last line, parameter, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

First see chrislondon answer, and then know that you can also do this --> **If you do not have access to the (context).**

```
navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
to clear route - 

  onTap: () {
                    //todo to clear route -
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UpdateEmployeeUpdateDateActivity(_token),));
                    widget.listener.onEmployeeDateClick(_day,_month, _year);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Newer Flutter version seem to replace

```dart
(Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

by

```dart
ModalRoute.withName('/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GetX makes it easier.

Get.offAll( ()=> Loginpage() ) //will remove all previous routes and navigate you to login page
Get.offNamed('/login_page')  //does the same thing.