# Flutter - Navigate to a new screen, and clear all the previous screens

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I used `Navigator.push` up to 6 screens to get to the payment page. After Payment, I want to push to the "Payment Successful" page then remove all the previous screens i.e using the back button will return to the very first screen.

NOTE: I have tried `pushReplacementNamed` and  it doesn't work.

Comment: No i did'nt. using `pushRepalcementNamed` takes me to a new route, but when I use the back button takes to to the last Named Route instead of the back button not working.

Comment: Perhaps you want to remove more previous routes like https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html but your question doesn't contain any information that would allow do diagnose your problem.

Comment: Yes. Just found out now. Thanks though.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I figured it out. It was the `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil` function. Where i had to pass the `PaymentSuccessful` widget as the `newRoute`, and the `"/Home"` route as the predicate

```
  _navPaymentSuccessful(){
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context, 
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PaymentSuccessful()
      ), 
     ModalRoute.withName("/Home")
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what's the purpose of using `ModalRoute.withName('/Home')` to complete your answer?

Comment: @iDecode You can refer to the documentation here [https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html] the ModalRoute.withName('/Home') is used to ensure that when the back button is pressed the user is navigated to the "/Home Screen" -> "To remove routes until a route with a certain name, use the RoutePredicate returned from ModalRoute.withName"

Comment: If you want to navigate to the `root` Screen, the replace `"/Home"` with `"/"`. And you can also provide route arguments to `MaterialPageRoute()` using his props `settings: RouteSettings(arguments: myArgs)`

Comment: to add more, here is the video explaining exactly this function: [Tutorial Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ae7m9JHhi7Y&ab_channel=LearnwithShajeel)

Comment: I found out that you don't need to specify the route with "/" but just write a predicate (_) => false. Here is my example:

```Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()), (_) => false);```

Answer (score 42):

Accepted Answer is correct. But you can try this too.

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<dynamic>(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => YourPageNameGoesHere(),
        ),
        (route) => false,//if you want to disable back feature set to false
);
```

Answer (score 17):

even simpler and I think a better way would be to do it this way,
this Schedules a callback for the end of the current persistent frame,to push to route `/loginPage` and removes all the previous routes,this way you can make sure that all the frames are rendered and then you navigate to next page.

```
 SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    '/loginPage', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
              });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would Suggest use WillPopScope in your Payment successful page and onWillPop method write following snippet of code:

```
 return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: (){
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/Home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      },
      child: Scaffold()
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you want pass arguments to new page:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      '/new-route-name',
      arguments: {
         any object
      },
      ModalRoute.withName("/the-route-name-that-you-want-back-to-it")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove just single screen from stack, then you can do with this

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(
                  RouteHelper.navbar, //this is our other route name
                  arguments: {code}, // this is the argument which we are sending to second screen
                );
```

Hope, it would be helpful for someone.