# How to go from one screen to another clearing all the previous screens from stack?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter project, I have three screens - **Screen0, Screen1, Screen2**. Now, from the **screen0** , I can go to the screen1 with a button click, then from **screen1** we can go to **screen2** with a button. In **screen2**, I have a button which I have used to go back to **screen0**. As **Screen0** is the initial screen, I want to clear all the previous screens when I come back to **Screen0** and don't want to have any back option like in this image-

[image]

And here's my code-

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screen0.dart';
import 'screen1.dart';
import 'screen2.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context)=> Screen0(),
        '/first': (context)=> Screen1(),
        '/second': (context)=> Screen2(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have set all the routes in my main.dart file. Then in the Screen0, I have a button to go to screen1 like below-

screen0.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class Screen0 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        title: Text('Screen 0'),
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text('Go to screen 1'),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/first');
              },
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }

}
```

In the screen1, I have a button to go to screen2-

```
class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        title: Text('Screen 1'),
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text('Go to screen 2'),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return Screen2();
                  })
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }

}
```

Now, in the screen2, i have the button to go to screen0 -

```
class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        title: Text('Screen 2'),
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text('Go to screen 0'),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pop(context, Screen2);
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
              },
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }

}
```

I have tried some solution like using Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil given in the below link-

[Flutter - Navigate to a new screen, and clear all the previous screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689049/flutter-navigate-to-a-new-screen-and-clear-all-the-previous-screens)

But this solution didn't work for me.

So, it would be nice if someone help me out this code to solve the problem.

Comment: In what way did `pushAndRemoveUntil` not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter remove all routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889341/flutter-remove-all-routes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use pushNamedAndRemoveUntil

for example

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/screen4', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```