# How to navigate to screen and remove all screen/route history [sign out functionality]

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes

How can i navigate to a screen and remove all previous routing history so that the user cannot press back and get to the previous screen?
In my case I want to push the login screen when a user is logged out, but the navigation history is still there so the user can just press back and return to the previous page.

```
What I have:
A -> B -> C       //Before signing out
A -> B -> C -> L  //After signing out

What I want:
A -> B -> C       //Before signing out
L                 //After signing out
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889341/flutter-remove-all-routes

kindly check this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Push to new screen and remove all previous screen

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage(),), (route) => false);
```

Push to new route and remove all previous routes

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, login_page_route, (route) => false);
```

`pushAndRemoveUntil` will remove all existing routes and push to new page.

Comment: I've seen this suggestion before, but when I execute the code I land on the page after the login: A -> B -> C becomes L -> A. If I press back I will return to the login page.

Comment: Make sure you are using pop on backpress. Because im using this on every sigout code

Comment: Yes, it also has 290+ upvotes in the other PR, so it should work.
What do you mean with pop on backpress. Isn't that handled by the flutter navigation framework?

Comment: The code you provided works, it's my firebase connection that had little bit of lag so when i signed out and checked my auth status it stil said authenticated and proceeded to login.
Thanks for your help buddy!

Comment: Ohh, Keep Growing ^^

Answer (score 2):

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('L'));
```

Comment: I'm not using named routes. Is there an equivalent version for routing worth screen arguments?