# Firebase Auth login and logout based on user's account status

Tags: flutter

I am making an application. I made an account system for the application. But I want to ask something. I separated the login screen and the normal application screens. If the user's account is not open, the login screen; If it is open, it is redirected to the application.

I wrote the following code for this:

`main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simto_todolist/app.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:simto_todolist/welcome_splashs.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
  var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: accountState(),
    );
  }
}

accountState() {
  if (user == null) {
    return splashScreen(); // login
  } else {
    return app(); // app
  }
}
```

I also put a logout button in my application. Pressing this button exits the application, but the application just freezes. So the app doesn't know what to do. Then I start the application from the beginning, it redirects to the login screen.

I believe this problem will be solved if I can constantly check that the user's account is open. How can I do this what I want?

The code I gave above only checks once, when the application starts. I want him to check it all the time.

---

After doing what Peter Koltai said, `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simto_todolist/app.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:simto_todolist/welcome_splashs.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
  var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthState>(
        create: (context) => AuthState()),
      ],
      builder: (context, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: context.watch<AuthState>().user == null ? 
          splashScreen() : app(),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}

class AuthState with ChangeNotifier {
  User _user;
  User get user => _user;
  set user(User currentUser) {
    _user = currentUser;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  MyAuthState() {   
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User currentUser) {
      user = currentUser;
    });
  }
}
```

The screen does not change when the user logs in in `splashScreen()`.

---

Login codes:

```
  RaisedButton(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 85, left: 85, top: 12, bottom: 12),
        child: Text("Login", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20, fontFamily: "Roboto-Thin"),),
    ),
    color: Colors.blue[400],
    textColor: Colors.white,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    ),
    onPressed: () async {
      if (_loginEmail.text.isEmpty || _loginPassword.text.isEmpty) {
        CoolAlert.show(
          context: context,
          type: CoolAlertType.error,
          title: "Error",
          text: "Please fill in all fields completely."
        );
      }
      else if(validateEmail (_loginEmail.text) != null) {
        CoolAlert.show(
          context: context,
          type: CoolAlertType.error,
          title: "Error",
          text: validateEmail (_loginEmail.text)
        );
      }
      else {
        try {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _loginEmail.text,
            password: _loginPassword.text,
          );
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
            CoolAlert.show(
              context: context,
              type: CoolAlertType.error,
              title: "Error",
              text: "No such user was found."
            );
          }
          else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
            CoolAlert.show(
              context: context,
              type: CoolAlertType.error,
              title: "Error",
              text: "Password is incorrect."
            );
          }
          else {
            CoolAlert.show(
              context: context,
              type: CoolAlertType.error,
              title: "Error",
              text: "An unknown error has occurred. Please try again later."
            );
          }
        }
      }
    },
  ),
```

---

Logout button codes:

```
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app, color: Colors.black, size: 22,),
  title: Text("Logout", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),),
  onTap: () {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set up a listener to authentication state changes like:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
  // execute any logic depending on current authentication state
});
```

This will be called when user is logged in or out. The next step is to update you application's home route based on this change. One possible solution is to use provider for state management, [check here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

Create a class in `main.dart` for the provider:

```
class AuthState with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  User? get user => _user;
  set user(User? currentUser) {
    _user = currentUser;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  AuthState() {   
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? currentUser) {
      user = currentUser;
    });
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and import it into `main.dart`.

After this you can create your `MaterialApp` like this (you don't really need `MultiProvider` but later if you add more providers it can be useful):

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthState>(
      create: (context) => AuthState()),
  ],
  builder: (context, child) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: context.watch<AuthState>().user == null ? 
        splashScreen() : app(),
    );
  });
```

**EDIT: simplified sample without Firebase Authentication**

This example demonstrates how the UI is updated on changes in the provider. It can be run on `dartpad.dev` as well and seems to work. In this example listening to authentication state changes I simply simulate it with explicitly setting an `int?` value, since during the tests the Firebase part worked, only UI was not updated on logout.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AuthState with ChangeNotifier {
  int? _user;
  int? get user => _user;
  set user(int? newUser) {
    _user = newUser;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthState>(create: (context) => AuthState()),
        ],
        builder: (context, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            home: context.watch<AuthState>().user == null
                ? const Login()
                : const Main(),
          );
        });
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
          body: Center(
              child: Column(children: [
        const Text('You are not logged in'),
        ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Login'),
            onPressed: () => context.read<AuthState>().user = 1)
      ])));
}

class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  const Main({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
          body: Center(
              child: Column(children: [
        const Text('You are logged in'),
        ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Logout'),
            onPressed: () => context.read<AuthState>().user = null)
      ])));
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I tried your code. When I say log out from profile, technically it logs out, but the screen doesn't change. How can I solve this? Is it possible to redirect to `splashScreen` with a code similar to the ones you gave, if the user's account is not open? Or does it make more sense to press the logout button and send it to `splashScreen`  with the `Navigator` ? Which would be more logical and functional?

Comment: @EmirBolat Hi, how do you perform log out exactly? If you use Firebase's logout function, it should work. Please put a breakpoint to the `user = currentUser;` line in the listener, and check if it stops there when you log out.

Comment: @EmirBolat If you already pushed routes on top of `home`, you need to remove all these routes on a logout. The above code will put `splashScreen` as `home`, but will not remove other routes.

Comment: @EmirBolat Check for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889341/flutter-remove-all-routes) on how to remove routes.

Comment: Koltay Hello. After logging in in the login section, it goes to the app section with the Navigator. Could it be that the screen is not updating because of this?

Comment: You don't need to use Navigator in this case, `app()` will be the home widget because of the code.

Comment: hello. I did what you said and deleted the Navigator code that runs when the user presses the login button in `splashScreen()`. But the screen still does not change. I placed the current codes in the `main.dart` file on the subject.

Comment: @EmirBolat Please share your current code, it is hard to tell without having a look at it.

Comment: Do I assign `app()` codes? Since it's a very long code, I'll just throw in the login part if you want.

Comment: Part where you make `login` is enough. Besides consider converting `MyApp` to `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: I added the login codes to the thread. Since there is a constant account query in the codes in the `main.dart` file (the codes you give), `Navigator` etc. I didn't add.

Comment: Does the listener get called when logging in?

Comment: I tried logging in. I also added a print to the `main.dart` codes you provided. The `main.dart` codes were not called.

Comment: In addition, after pressing the login button for trial purposes, I put the code to go to the app with `Navigator`. It's gone, but when I restart the application, it redirects to `splashScreen` again. So whether I'm logged in or not, it redirects to the login screen.

Comment: @EmirBolat I made a mistake. Rename the constructor from MyAuthState to AuthState. The listener was not added because of this mistake. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did what you said and after pressing the login button it logged in. But this time, when I press the logout button in the application, it technically logs out but does not redirect to the login section. I tried 10 times, only 1 of them was direct, it quickly led to the entrance. He did not direct others. Sorry for making you tired. I'd be very grateful if you could help. I put the codes of the logout button on the topic.

Comment: At the time hen the logout happens, are there any routes pushed above the `home` route? How does you `Navigator` stack look like?

Comment: I did not use any `Navigator` on logout. I didn't put `Navigator` because it constantly checks the codes you gave. I placed the codes in the topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244305/discussion-between-peter-koltai-and-emir-bolat).

Comment: @EmirBolat It frustrates me a little that the code I gave you does not work. I don't understand it. I prepared a small example that you can run on dartpad.dev as well. It does not contain the Firebase authentication, but simply sets a user to null or 1. I will add it as an edit to my answer. It works, on login / logout the UI is updated. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Your code before that worked like a miracle. I just ran the following code when the logout button was pressed:
`AuthState().user = null;`
I'm so suprized now. I guess the listener was triggered automatically because there was a change. Thank you very much for your help. Thank you for taking the time for me. <3

Comment: So good to hear :-) You are welcome.