# Crash after reset scenes because of focus

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to make login logout system , every thing works fine
but one scene has auto focus
so when I open the following
login --> focus scene --> logout --> login --> focus scene , after will crash

there is dispose

```
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _inputFocusNode.dispose();
        _textController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
```

here when logout:

```
await Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                  .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      '/login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false,);
```

- I run it on web (google chrome)
- flutter SDK 3.3.4
- Mac os

[image: when it crash]

Comment: Provide crash logs as well.

Comment: thank you for reply 
error something like this 
Locations: No module for http://localhost:61308/dart_sdk.js

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer with the little code snippet. Check if your routes are configured.

Example:

```
routes: {
// When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
'/': (context) => const FirstScreen(),
// When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
'/second': (context) => const SecondScreen(),
},
```

Also refer to this stack overflow, if this helps;
[Flutter remove all routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889341/flutter-remove-all-routes)

Comment: thank you for reply 
I am using Getx , and all pages in the list 

 `
 'debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      getPages: appRoutes(),
      initialRoute: '/',
      initialBinding: MainBinding(),
      transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
      theme: appTheme,'
`